# In HQL convert String to time using MySQL

Tags: mysql, hibernate, hql

I have time in string in a column and I want to convert it into datetime so that I can sort the time. How do I achieve this?

I am using HQL query and having mySQL database:

```
Select txtClassTimings FROM Mststudenttimetable
```

txtClassTimings contains time like 8:30 am, 9:30 am, 10:30 am but this is all in string. I want it in datetime in order to sort.

Answer (score 0):

YOu can use [@Formula](http://www.concretepage.com/hibernate/formula_hibernate_annotation) annotation and define an expression to extract time part and use it in your entity.

```
@Formula(" <SQL expression to extract time here> ")
public long time;
```

Comment: The query will retrieve 10-20 rows which will be string. Again I will need it in Datetime.